# Learning Nested Loops C++ confused with example

Tags: c++, edx

Hello taking an online class on nested loops and this was provided as the example but I don't really know what is going on.

The following code example shows nesting for loops to output a chess or checkerboard representation using the characters X and O. Why do we need x and y variables to execute a certain amount of times. And what does alternate = !alternate; mean? About the x and y wouldn't it just do it 8 times total because its greater than the amount of times y supplies? what is the difference in purpose for the two for statements? Thank you.

```
for (int x = 0; x < 8; x++)
{
   for (int y = 0; y < 4; y++)
     {
        if (alternate)
        {
        cout << "X ";
        cout << "O ";

    }
    else
    {
        cout << "O ";
        cout << "X ";

    }
}
alternate = !alternate;

cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Fix your indenting, it's very misleading. You seem to have some issues understanding what nested loops do, try asking your teacher.

Answer (score 0):

The variable x used for the number of lines you want to print X-O pairs. Variable y used to specify the number of X-O pairs in 1 line. So for printing 8 lines of X-O pairs and in each line, 4 pairs of X-O, you should do just like that.

The operator '!' used for getting the opposite of a value (it's logical NOT) (for example, 1 to 0 or false to true). so alternate = !alternate; means that after every line of X-O pairs, it changes from true to false or vise versa.

So lines' first character (X or O) will change according to 'alternate' variable.